# Mysql connect to server without any database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection-string

In my program C# program I need to create several mysql databases if they don't exist on the mysql server.

So I created a connection string to the server:

```
add name="ServerConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=7070;uid=root;password=pass;"     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Once the databases are created how can I use the existing connection to connect to one of the databases ?

Should there be a connection string for each database on the mysql server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to create separate connectionstrings in your config file for each database you have the need to create.
You could use the, not so well known, class called `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` living in the usual namespace `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

This class allows to specify any single key/value pair required by your connectionstring.
It also accepts, as a constructor parameter, a previous connection string that is internally splitted in the various key/value pairs and then it exposes these key/value pairs as properties of an instance of the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`.
This permits to change one property (the Database for example) and then rebuild a connection string with the updated values.

So for example you could write

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuidler mcb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder("yourinitialconnectionstring");
mcb.Database = "yournewdatabasename";
string newConnString = mcb.GetConnectionString(true);
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(newConnString))
{
    ...... 
}
```

The final call to `GetConnectionString` requires a boolean value set to true if you want the connectionstring returned to contain the password.

(Example based on MySql Provider 6.3.6)